# python, Regex, grab a substring that starts with a certain string and end with a certain string

Tags: python, regex, string

I have a string that looks like this.

```
"Correct! groupSum(0, [10, 2, 2, 5], 9) result: True  expected: True groupSum: passed 13 out of 13 AAAAAAAA"
```

I want to grab

```
'passed 13 out of 13'
```

portion of the string using Regex module. 
How can this be done?

I don't know much about regex modules, and all the answers I looked up involves lots of crazy expressions that I just don't understand. Please explain what each expressions mean

Comment: `re.search('passed \d+.*?\d+', string).group()`

Answer (score -1):

It's not super clear to me what the desired start and end strings in your example are. Do you want something like `groupSum: (.*) AAAAAAAA`, which will capture any number of characters  between "groupSum: " and " AAAAAAAA"? Or are you trying to match the format "passed # out of #"? If so, Coldspeed's comment is what you're looking for. \d+ means "one or more digits", so `passed \d+ out of \d+` will find the string.

Note that the `re.search` method is needed here, instead of `re.match`, since you need to find matches within the middle of the string and not just at the beginning.

Comment: Answers should answer the question, not ask for further clarification. What you posted belongs into a comment.